# Nested SELECT in counting average value of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

1. Wokers - holds employee id, company of employment, kind of contract (let's say "a" or "b")

   ```
   +----+------------+----------+
   | id | company_id | contract |
   +----+------------+----------+
   |  1 |          1 | a        |
   |  2 |          1 | b        |
   |  3 |          3 | b        |
   |  4 |          2 | a        |
   +----+------------+----------+
   ```
2. Companies - holds company id and company name.

   ```
   +----+--------------+
   | id | company_name |
   +----+--------------+
   |  1 | Company 1    |
   |  2 | Company 2    |
   |  3 | Company 3    |
   |  4 | Company 4    |
   +----+--------------+
   ```

What i want to do is to select average amount of employees in every company combined employed on two kinds of contracts.
Here is what I wrote:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM Workers
   WHERE `contract` = 'a') / (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                FROM Companies) 'Contract A',
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM Workers
   WHERE `contract` = 'b') / (SELECT COUNT(*)
                               FROM Companies)  'Contract B';
```

And also:

```
SELECT
  sum(case when `contract` = 'a'
    then 1
      else 0 end) / (SELECT COUNT(*)
                     FROM Companies) 'Contract A',
  sum(case when `rodzaj contract` = 'uop'
    then 1
      else 0 end) / (SELECT COUNT(*)
                     FROM Companies) 'Contract B'
FROM Workers;
```

Which one is more efficient? Is there any easier way? I am using MySQL.

Expected output would be Contract A - 0,5, Contract B - 0,5, becouse there are 2 people on Contract A in 4 Companies and 2 poeple on Contract B in these same 4 Companies

Comment: What does "average amount of employees" mean? Perhaps you could include the expected output to clarify your question?

Comment: Expected output would be Contract A - 0,5, Contract B - 0,5, becouse there are 2 people on Contract A in 4 Companies and 2 poeple on Contract B in these same 4 Companies

Comment: Add that to your question instead.

Comment: "Which one is more efficient" Whats are the indexes and the used table engine? show some `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` statements

Comment: MySQL. I added it into question.

Comment: MySQL is a database not a table engine..

Comment: Let's say InnoDB. It doesn't matter right now.

Comment: "Let's say InnoDB. It doesn't matter right now." Yes it does for preformance.. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Companies` would cause a full table scan or full index scan on the Companies table on the InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for:

```
SELECT SUM(contract = 'a') / c.cnt as contract_a,
       SUM(contract = 'b') / c.cnt as contract_b
FROM Workers w CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM Companies) c;
```

Or, if you can deal with the results on separate rows:

```
select contract, count(*) / cnt
from Workers w cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from Companies) c
group by contract, cnt;
```

As for performance, putting the `count(*)` query in the `FROM` clause guarantees that it is evaluated only once.  Hence that would seem to be a performance gain.

Also, only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Try to use column aliases that don't need to be escaped.

Comment: SELECT
  contract,
  COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Companies) AS average
FROM Workers
GROUP BY contract;
 Worked as well. Why is that?

Comment: @steve1337 . . . Why?  It is also legitimate syntax.  I am guessing that MySQL will evaluate the subquery once for every row in the result set, but it might have an optimization that runs it only once.